# loading a element of same file through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file *data.php*, when a user clicks update the database is updated in background with jquery but in response i want to reload the particular table whose data was updated.

my html:

```
<div id="divContainer">
<table id="tableContainer" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' border='0'>
<tr>
    <td>No.</td>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td>Usage Left</td>
    <td>%</td>
</tr><!-- Multiple rows with different data (This is head of table) -->
```

my jquery:

```
$('#UpdateAll').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'update.php',
            data: 'action=updateAll',

            success: function(response) {
                $('#response').fadeOut('500').empty().fadeIn('500').append(response);

                $('<div id="divContainer" />').slideUp('500').empty().load('data.php #tableContainer', function() {
                    $(this).hide().appendTo('#divContainer').slideDown('1000');
                });
            }
            });     
        });
```

Everything is working fine the database is getting updated and in success `#response` is getting loaded with success message but the table is not refreshing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#UpdateAll').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'update.php',
        data: 'action=updateAll',

        success: function (response) {
            $('#response').fadeOut('500').empty().fadeIn('500').append(response);

            $('#divContainer').slideUp('1000').load('data.php #tableContainer', function () {
                $(this).hide().appendTo('#tableContainer').slideDown('1000');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It looked at first like this was duplicated from the question, but on close inspection I see some differences.  Could you edit this to indicate if this is what you changed to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

You already have a div with an id of divContainer but you are creating this element again

```
$('<div id="divContainer " />').slideUp....
```

you need

```
$('#divContainer')
         .slideUp('500')
         .empty()
         .load('data.php #tableContainer', function() {
             $(this).slideDown('1000');
          });
```